# Determine whether a car can get around a route with a limited amount of gas

Tags: code-golf, string

Using any programming language that supports functions, have the function

```
is_enough(strArr)
```

that take `strArr` which will be an an array consisting of the following elements:

- `N` which will be the number of gas stations in a circular route
- and each subsequent element will be the string `g:c` where

  - `g` is the amount of gas in gallons at that gas station and
  - `c` will be the amount of gallons of gas needed to get to the following gas station.

For example `strArr` may be:

```
["4","3:1","2:2","1:2","0:1"].
```

Your goal is to return the index of the starting gas station that will allow you to travel around the whole route once, otherwise return the string *"impossible"*.

For the example above there are *4* gas stations, and your program should return the string *"1"* because:

- Starting at station *1* you receive *3* gallons of gas and spend *1* getting to the next station.
- Then you have *2* gallons + *2* more at the next station and you spend *2* so you have *2* gallons when you get to the 3rd station.
- You then have *3* but you spend *2* getting to the final station,
- At the final station you receive *0* gallons and you spend your final gallon getting to your starting point.

Starting at any other gas station would make getting around the route impossible, so the answer is *"1"*.

If there are multiple gas stations that are possible to start at, return the smallest index (of the gas station). `N` will be `>= 2`.

Correct Sample Outputs:

```
Input: ["4","1:1","2:2","1:2","0:1"]
Output: "impossible"

Input: ["4","0:1","2:2","1:2","3:1"]
Output: "4"
```

The winner will be the one to use the shortest code although it will be long.

Comment: What's the objective winning criterion? I'm voting to close because there's no way to tell who the winner is.

Comment: Just put a code-golf tag on it and it'll be ok.

Comment: Voting to close just because of a missing tag is a bit draconian, wouldn’t you say? Just add the tag.

Comment: Are there always precisely `N+1` elements in `strArr`?  This would make `N` redundant in case the language already provides a way of getting the length of the array, right? (it'd still be useful for e.g. C though.)

Comment: Two of the answers are interpreting the spec as requiring the name `is_enough` (9 chars); three are using a single-char name, and one doesn't name the function at all. Could you please clarify what is permissible?

Answer (score 1):

## Bash <strike>178</strike> <strike>170</strike> <strike>161</strike> 157

Rather straight forward.

```
is_enough(){((t=(n=$1-1)<0))&&echo impossible||(x=(n ${@:3} $2);for z in ${@:2};do(((t+=${z%:*}-${z#*:})<0))&&is_enough ${x[*]}&&return;done;echo $[$#-++n])}
```

Spaced out:

```
is_enough() {
     ((t=(n=$1-1)<0)) && echo impossible || (
         x=(n ${@:3} $2);
         for z in ${@:2};do
             (((t+=${z%:*}-${z#*:})<0)) && is_enough ${x[*]} && return;
         done;
         echo $[$#-++n]
     )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 111

Here's a Ruby solution using `eval`:

```ruby
is_enough=->a{_,*s=a
"#{(1..s.size).find{|i|g=0;s.rotate(i-1).all?{|x|g+=eval x.tr ?:,?-;g>=0}}||:impossible}"}
```

Example usage:

```ruby
is_enough[%w(4 3:1 2:2 1:2 0:1)] #=> "1"
is_enough[%w(4 1:1 2:2 1:2 0:1)] #=> "impossible"
is_enough[%w(4 0:1 2:2 1:2 3:1)] #=> "4"
is_enough[%w(4 1:2 2:1 4:3 0:1)] #=> "2"
is_enough[%w(4 0:1 2:2 1:2 3:1)] #=> "4"
is_enough[%w(4 0:1 0:1 4:1 0:1)] #=> "3"
is_enough[%w(8 0:1 0:1 4:1 0:1 2:1 3:1 0:0 0:1)] #=> "3"
```

**EDIT**: Corrected function name and return type.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (70)

```
{×⍴G←Z/⍨0∧.≤¨+\¨¯1⌽⌽∘K¨Z←⍳⍴K←{⎕ML←3⋄-/⍎¨⍵⊂⍨⍵≠':'}¨1↓⍵:⊃G⋄'impossible'}
```

Explanation:

- `1↓⍵`: drop the first element (length), we don't need it
- `{`...`}¨`: for each of the gas stations...

  - `⎕ML←3`: set `⎕ML` to 3 within the inner function (changes behaviour of `⊂`)
  - `⍵⊂⍨⍵≠':'`: split the string on `:`
  - `⍎¨`: evaluate each part
  - `-/`: subtract the second number from the first (giving net effect for each gas station)
- `K←`: store them in K
- `Z←⍳⍴K`: get the indices for the gas station (`1` to length of `K`), store in `Z`
- `⌽∘K¨Z`: rotate `K` by each value of `Z`, giving an array of arrays
- `¯1⌽`: rotate this array to the left by 1 (to put the unchanged one first instead of last)
- `+\¨`: make a running sum for each inner array
- `0∧.≤¨`: for each running sum, see if there are negative values
- `Z/⍨`: select from `Z` those elements for which the running sum had no negative values
- `×⍴G←`: store in `G`. If `G` has any elements:
- `:⊃G`: return the first element of `G`.
- `⋄'impossible'`: otherwise, return `impossible`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 132

```
g=->a{n,*a=a.map{|e|e.split(?:).map &:to_i}
(r=(0...n[0]).find{|i|a.rotate(i).inject(0){|m,(j,k)|m&&m>=0&&m+j-k}})?r+1:"impossible"}
```

Test:

```
irb(main):003:0> g[["4","1:1","2:2","1:2","0:1"]]
=> "impossible"
irb(main):004:0> g[["4","0:1","2:2","1:2","3:1"]]
=> 4
```

Comment: Spec requires a string to be returned in all cases.

Comment: @boothby I can't find that requirement anywhere in the spec. Can you quote?

Comment: For the example above there are 4 gas stations, and your program should return the string "1" because:

Comment: Ah screw it; Chron's solution is much shorter anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 131

I find this one-liner fairly satisfying.

```
E=lambda s:([`i`for i in range(1,len(s)+1)if reduce(lambda r,t:r+eval(t[0]+'-'+t[-1])*(r>=0),s[i:]+s[1:i],0)>=0]+['impossible'])[0]
```

Comment: what is `reduce()` here? I am getting an error `NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined`

Comment: @ErHarshRathore this is Python 2. In Python 3, `reduce` is still in the standard lib, but it was moved to the `functools` module.

Comment: Yeah! I got it `from functools import reduce` thanks

Comment: @ErHarshRathore Additionally the backticks `\`i\`` here is equivalent to `str(i)` in Python 3.

Comment: Do you thing this post should be updated now to python 3.x?

Comment: @ErHarshRathore No. Python 2 is still a language. Python 3 is a different language. If you wish to code golf it in 3, you can post an answer in that different language.

Answer (score 0):

### GolfScript (72 chars)

```
{(~\{':'/{~}/-}%[\),1>{;.{1$-1>*+}*-1>\(+\},~"impossible"]1=}:is_enough;
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=eyh%2BXHsnOicve359Ly19JVtcKSwxPns7LnsxJC0xPiorfSotMT5cKCtcfSx%2BImltcG9zc2libGUiXTE9fTppc19lbm91Z2g7CgpbIjQiICIxOjEiICIyOjIiICIxOjIiICIwOjEiXWlzX2Vub3VnaCBwClsiNCIgIjA6MSIgIjI6MiIgIjE6MiIgIjM6MSJdaXNfZW5vdWdoIHAKWyI0IiAiMzoxIiAiMDoxIiAiMjoyIiAiMToyIl1pc19lbm91Z2ggcA%3D%3D)

This performs the obvious brute force approach. The most interesting bit IMO is the determination of whether the partial sums of an array of delta-fuel ever drops below 0:

```
{1$-1>*+}*-1>
```

This saves 1 char over the more obvious

```
[{1$+}*]{0<},!
```

If the output were indexed at 0 rather than at 1, an alternative approach to rotating the array would be preferable:

```
{(;{':'/{~}/-}%:A[,,{A\{(+}*{1$-1>*+}*-1>},~"impossible"]0=}:is_enough;
```

But this approach isn't easily adopted to indexing at 1:

```
{(;{':'/{~}/-}%:A[,),1>{A\({(+}*{1$-1>*+}*-1>},~"impossible"]0=}:is_enough;
```

or

```
{(;{':'/{~}/-}%:A[,,{A\{(+}*{1$-1>*+}*-1>},{)}%~"impossible"]0=}:is_enough;
```